# QML background from QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt

How can I set a background using C++ object declared in QML file that returns QPixmap by one of its methods.

Comment: Show the relevant part of the code you already wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to implement QDeclarativeImageProvider, [here](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-qdeclarativeimageprovider-to-load.html) is sample code.